# Clarifications needed on Designing Data Access Object (DAO) Layer - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dao, rapid7

I am trying to setup a DAO layer for a Spring boot project for which
i came across this [helpful blog](https://www.rapid7.com/blog/post/2016/09/01/designing-data-access-object-dao-layer/?__hstc=44907643.ac5a80cf7e168316af0c9bbef9b87814.1475971200054.1475971200055.1475971200056.1&__hssc=44907643.1.1475971200057&__hsfp=1773666937)  .

I need some clarity on the below text , especially the part where it says that dependencies must not be implementation classes and that they  need not exceed their domain.

> "all DAO classes must get their dependencies injected through
> instantiation, not later at runtime, **and dependencies must not be
> implementation classes. The DAO layer must ensure that bare minimum of
> dependencies DAO class needs does not exceed its domain**, i.e. all
> dependencies should be interfaces related to persistence layer or
> other DAO interfaces only."

Kindly help/add/correct my understanding by providing some pointers . What i understood is

> We should inject interfaces as
> dependencies in service class instead of auto wiring the concrete
> persistence layer implementation class .

Comment: Read through articles which has examples. In general we prefer to instantiate interface in the calling class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't inject the interfaces, your service class depends on the DAO interfaces (but does not see the implementation). You inject the implementations of the dao interfaces at runtime. So, the implementations will also depend on the dao interfaces.

The idea being that (in theory) you could swap out your underlying implementations - migrate from file system, to relational database, to a document db and your service will not be impacted.